# Why does a left inverse not have to be surjective?

Tags: functions

My book says:

> Assume $A\neq 0$ and let $f:A\to B$ be a function. Then $f$ has a left inverse if and only if it is injective.

Let the left inverse of $f$ be $g$. Then we have $g\circ f=id_A$. Obviously $g:B\to A$. I wonder why $f$ does not have to be surjective. If $f$ is not surjective, then clearly some points of $B$ are not mapped by $g$, which disqualifies $g$ from being called a function!

Can someone please shed some light on this?

Comment: The book says the same. I quote: "If $f:A\to B$ has a left inverse, then there exists a $g:B\to A$ such that $g\circ f=id_A$.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.It boils down to the definition of $\circ$.

Comment: @GitGud- On a related note, why does the **right** inverse $g$ of $f$ not have to be **injective**? Say $f(a)=f(b)$ for $a\neq b$. Then $g(f(a))=g(f(b))$ will have two images. This is a contradiction.

Comment: "*clearly some points of $B$ are not mapped by $g$*" Hmm, what makes you say that?

Comment: Let's start from somewhere concrete. If $g\circ f = I_A$, then we are guaranteed $f$ is 1-1 and $g$ is onto, and we can conclude nothing else about $f$ and $g$. Now *if* $g$ also has a left inverse $h$, so that $h\circ g=I_B$ then we could (by the same token) conclude $g$ is 1-1 and $h$ is onto, and moreover that $f=h$.

Comment: "*why does the right inverse g of f not have to be injective*" $g$ isn't a right inverse of $f$, $f$ is a right inverse of $g$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A = B = \mathbb{N}$ and let $$
  f(n) = n+1 \text{.}
$$
Then $g(n) = n-1$ is obviously a left inverse since $(n + 1) - 1 = n$. Yet $f$ is not surjective - $f(\mathbb{N}) = \mathbb{N}\setminus\{0\}$.

You might object that, the way I defined it, $g$ *isn't* a function from $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$, since $g(0)$ isn't defined. You're right of course, but that doesn't really matter, because $f(n) \neq 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, so the value of $g(0)$ doesn't affect whether $g(f(n)) = n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. So you can just set $g(0) = 0$, and $g$ is still a left-inverse of $f$, and $f$ is still not surjective.

Also note that the corrected definition of $g$, i.e. $$
  g(n) = \begin{cases} n-1 &\text{if $n \neq 0$} \\
                       0    &\text{otherwise} \end{cases}
$$
is *not* injective - you have $g(1) = g(0) = 0$. And since $f$ is $g$'s right-inverse, it follows that while a function *must* be injective (but not necessarily surjective) to have a left-inverse, it *doesn't* need to be injective (but does needs to be surective) to have a right-inverse.

Comment: 1. $0\notin\Bbb{N}$. 2. $g(n)$ is not a left inverse, as it does not act from $B$ to $A$. It acts from $B\setminus\{1\}\to A$

Comment: @algebraically_speaking For the purpose of this answer, $0 \in \mathbb{N}$. For 2. - yeah, I was a bit sloppy there, fixed it now.

Comment: @algebraically_speaking Plus, the whole point is that the value of $g(0)$ is utterly irrelevant, since $0 \not\in f(\mathbb{N})$

Comment: In spite of the fact that I agree with the idea, saying $0\in \mathbb N$ doesn't solve the problem. Now the OP can just ask about $g(-1)$. Of course the answer is the same.

Comment: @GitGud True, but the updated answer now says "Just set $g(0)=0$". My point remains that obessing with $g(0)$ is a bit of a smoke-screen, because the value $0$ is never taken by $f$. Which is exactly the point here - if the codomain of $f$ is larger than the image of the domain, $f$ isn't surjective, yet might very well have a left-inverse.

Comment: I too will adopt $\Bbb N=\{0,1,2,\ldots\}$. If one just says "Let $g$ be given by $g(n)=n-1$ for $n>0$ and $g(0)=0$, there should not be any argument here about $g$ being a function. $gf=1_N$, $fg\neq I_N$, and everything is illustrated very nicely since $f$ isn't onto $\Bbb N$ and $g$ isn't $1-1$. Great answer: basically what I would have said +1

Answer (score 1):

$f$ need not to be surjective because $g\circ f$ is defined even if the image of $f$ is not the whole domain of $g$.

Example. Let $A\subset B$ non empty, and $f:A\to B$ the inclusion, that is to say $f(x)=x$. 
Define the map $g:B\to A$ as follows. Let $a_0\in A$ any point (which exists because $A\neq\emptyset$) then set:

$$g(x)=x\qquad\text{ for } x\in A$$
$$g(x)=a_0\qquad \text{ for } x\notin A$$

$g$ is a left inverse of $f$.

Comment: @user126154- On a related note, why does the **right** inverse $g$ of $f$ not have to be **injective**? Say $f(a)=f(b)$ for $a\neq b$. Then $g(f(a))=g(f(b))$ will have two images. This is a contradiction.

Comment: I don't understand your comment, could you explain better? (and also, are we talking of right or left inverses?)

Comment: @user126154- In the question, we're talking about left inverses. Now, we're talking about right inverses. A right inverse has to be surjective. I'm asking why it does not have to be injective too. Let $g$ be the right inverse of $f$. Then $f:A\to B$ and $g: B\to A$.

Comment: OK. In the case of right inverse, then yes, the right inverse need to be injective. As you proved.

Comment: @user126154- But my book says it need only be surjective. And considering it is a published well-known book, it is unlikely it carries an error of this sort. I've seen the same result in multiple places elsewhere.

Comment: Let's clarify: a right inverse of $f:A\to B$ is a function $g:B\to A$ such that $f(g(b))=b$ for all $b\in B$. Do we agree?

Comment: If so, if $g(b)=g(b')$ then $b=f(g(b))=f(g(b'))=b'$. Thus $g$ is ijnective.

Comment: Are you sure that your book say that the right inverse is only surjective? Could you chek? I suspect that your book says that $f$ has a right inverse if and only if it is surjective.

Comment: @algebraically_speaking A right-inverse *clearly* must be injective. Apart from being trivially shown, as user126154 did, it also follows from your question. After all, if $f$ has a right-inverse $g$, then $f$ is $g$'s *left-inverse*! Which, as your question states, must be injective!

Comment: What is the $a_0$ for?

Comment: @JacksonH $a_0$ is just a point of $A$ (as specified in the answer). Nothing more that a point of $A$, that I chosed to name $a_0$ for no specific reason.