# Example of right inverse which is not injective.

Tags: functions

My book says

> Let $f:A\to B$ be a function where $A\neq\emptyset$. Then $f$ has a right inverse $g:B\to A$ iff it is surjective.

It sounds like surjectivity is a **sufficient** condition for $f$ to have a right inverse. Could someone please give an example of such a right inverse which is **not injective**?

Answer (score 1):

> Could someone please give an example of such a right inverse which is **not injective**?

No, you cannot find a right inverse that isn't injective.

If fg=1 and g(x)=g(y), then fg(x)=fg(y), but this last equation says x=y. Thus, g is 1-1.

This seems to be well covered at your other question: [Why does a left inverse not have to be surjective?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/706841/why-does-a-left-inverse-not-have-to-be-surjective#comment1480010_706841)

Comment: @rschweib- You're right. I think I missed the point though. It is not the injectivity of the inverse we're concerned about. It is the injectivity/surjectivity of $f$.

Comment: @algebraically_speaking Nobody said you asked the same question, I just meant the answer to this one is covered there already.

Comment: Hmm, not sure what there is to downvote: this is pretty clear-cut. Maybe the OP is down voting because they meant to ask something else but haven't worded it correctly?

Answer (score -2):

A right inverse for $f$ is a function $g: B \rightarrow A$ such that $f(g(y)) = y \text{ for  each } y \in B$. So this implies $f$ has to be surjective.[This link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function#Left_and_right_inverses) contains all the details you need.

Comment: Let $A = \{1, 2\}, B = \{1\}$ and $f(1)=1, f(2)=1$ then $f$ has two  right inverse

Comment: I don't understand the example in the link. $f:\Bbb{R}\to [0,\infty)$ is defined as $f(x)=x^2$ and $g:[0,\infty)\to \Bbb{R}$ is defined as $g(x)=\sqrt{x}$. But $g$ is not surjective! How can it be the right inverse?? The image of $g$ is only $[0,\infty)$ and **not** $\Bbb{R}$.

Comment: your book says $f$ has to be surjective not $g$.